# navigation controller: moving back 2 screens?

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, swift2

I have a `delete` function in my App and from there I need to go back 2 screens and then reload a table. The table will reload ok but if I use a `segue` then my `navigationcontroller` goes out of `sync`. Is there a way to move back 2 screens when the user clicks a `button`?

I have tried this and I am getting an **error**:

> self.navigationController!.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

```
Error: #0   0x00000001004465dc in specialized
_fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt) -> () () Thread1 EXC_BREAKPOINT (Code 1, subcode 0x1004465dc)
```

I have a `UITabBarController` and also a `RootViewController` and want to go back to the initial screen that is used when I open the app.

Comment: "I am getting an error" Oh really? Would you like to reveal _what_ error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

I can extend a helping hand to try to help you with navigation. The easiest way to have a button trigger a segue would be to Control+Click+Drag to the ViewController of your choice and then select a particular segue. This would automatically wire up in IB.

Say you wanted to do it manually through code, you could go ahead and do that by naming the segue (You still have to create the segue in IB before you can name the identifier) and then trigger with the following code I stumbled across many moons ago when I was first learning:

```
 @IBAction func about(sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("about", sender: sender)
}
```

Hope this helps, I am happy to try to further explain or amend my post if this does not solve your problem.